# Number minus Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was looking at some legacy code, and I noticed the following code (simplified here):

```
const age = [ 33 ];
const year = 2021;
const yearOfBirth = year - age; // gives the number 1988
```

In other words, `number - [number]` is of type `number`

If, however I change it to

```
const age = [ 33, 44 ];
```

The subtraction doesn't work and I get `NaN`. This makes sense to me.

*Why is the first operation valid? Where is such thing documented?*

---

PS: I'm aware a similar thing holds for `string[]`, since `String.prototype.toString()` is equivalent to `String.prototype.join("")`. But I don't know why this holds for numbers.

Comment: the array it goes `toString` by using `join` the result is a string. by only a single item, you get a stringed number and by using `-` it converts the value to a number.

Comment: `String.prototype.join` doesn't exist.

Comment: `Array.prototype.toString` uses `Array.prototype.join` internally.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question:

> Why is the first operation valid? Where is such thing documented?

`2021 - [33]` is interpreted like this:

First, the array `[33]` is converted to a primitive, which means that `toString` is applied, which mean it's interpreted as `"33"`

Second, the string `"33"` is subtracted from the number `2021`. To do that, it is first converted to a number, and then subtracted. This works OK because `"33"` can be converted to the number `33`.

`2021 - [33,44]` is interpreted similarly:

First, the array `[33,44]` is converted to a primitive, applying `toString`, which produces `"33,44"`. Second, this is converted to a number, producing `NaN`, and that means that the subtraction results in `NaN`.

It is documented at https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.6.2, https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-9.3, https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-9.1 and https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-8.12.8

But the code is clearly not ideal and should really be fixed.

Comment: I already fixed it. I came up with the problem while replacing all the typescript `any` `any` `any` in the code by its real types. I should have figured out the `toString` casting and would have saved me from asking the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is because `[33].toString()` becomes `"33"` and `[33, 44].toString()` becomes `"33,44"` which cannot be evaluated to either `int` or `float`.

[image: Array.prototype.toString()]